# Solving $\sin(2x)>0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

$\sin(2x)>0$

I did

$$\sin(2x) > 0 \Leftrightarrow\\
\arcsin(\sin(2x)) > \arcsin(0) \Leftrightarrow \\
2x > 2\pi*k   \lor 2x >2\pi*k+\pi \Leftrightarrow \\
x > \pi*k\lor x > \pi*k + \pi/2$$

Is this correct? I think the sign is the other way around. If yes, why? Is it because I used an inverse function?

Answer (score 5):

We simply have by definition of $\sin \theta$ as the $y$ coordinate of the point on the unitary circle

$$\sin(2x)>0 \iff  2k\pi <2x <\pi+2k\pi, \quad k\in\mathbb Z$$

[image]

Note that the solution by the inverse is not a good option since inverse trigonometric functions only works on specific range.

For example $$\arcsin(\sin(\theta))=\theta$$ is only true for $\theta \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.

This is not an effective and convenient way to solve in this case. Just refer to the definitin as indicated.

Comment: But how do you get to that answer?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire By definition on the unitary circle $y=\sin \theta$ is positive for $0<\theta <\pi$ and it is also true adding multiple of $2\pi$ both side. We don't need other than this.

Comment: I see but what if it was 3x instead of 2x?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire The same argument works for any $\sin (f(x))$ that is $$\sin(f(x))>0 \iff  2k\pi <f(x)<\pi+2k\pi, \quad k\in\mathbb Z$$

Answer (score 2):

The sine is positive in the quadrants I and II. Hence

$$2x\in(0+2k\pi,\pi+2k\pi)$$ and

$$x\in\left(k\pi,\frac\pi2+k\pi\right).$$

Comment: This is exactly my solution!